# Apply css styles to popup window using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp with multiple div's. I am getting the whole div data using `innerHTML` and displaying it to popup window. By using this I'm unable to get all the css styles.

Here is the function:

```
function popupWin(cs) {
  var divText1 = document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML;
  var divText2 = document.getElementById("divId"+cs).innerHTML;
  var divText3 = document.getElementById("divId"+cs+"abc").innerHTML;
  var myWindow = window.open('',"mywindow","status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,addressbar=no,height=600,width=800");
  var doc = myWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write('<link href="styles/shared/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
  doc.write('<link href="styles/parent/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />');
  doc.write('<link href="styles/parent/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />');
  doc.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/admintool.css" />');
  doc.write(divText1);
  doc.write(divText2);
  doc.write(divText3);
  doc.close();
}
```

By using this function only some styles are working.

Comment: Where's the jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Try writing head tags around the style links, and body tags around the content.